# Play songs with BackgroundMediaPlayer

Tags: c#, audio, windows-phone-8.1, media-player

I'm trying to play songs from a List of StorageFile. I can load all the songs but I don't know how I can play them using the `BackgroundMediaPlayer`

This is what I've got so far:

UI

```
        <Button Content="Load" x:Name="loadbutton" Height="100" Width="100" Click="loadButton_Click"/>
        <ListView x:Name="FolderList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="250" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Name="TextBlockAlbum" Text="{Binding DisplayName}" Tapped="Album_Tapped" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

The Button loads all my albums and displays them in my ListView. When I tap on the ListView, all the songs from the album should be played using the BackgroundMediaPlayer (this doesn't work)

Click on Button:

```
    private async void loadButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            await RetriveFilesInFolders(listOfFiles, folder);
            var ListOfAlbum = (await folder.GetFoldersAsync(CommonFolderQuery.GroupByAlbum)).ToList();
            FolderList.ItemsSource = ListOfAlbum; //ListView contains Albums
    }

    private async Task RetriveFilesInFolders(List<StorageFile> list, StorageFolder parent)
    {
        foreach (var item in await parent.GetFilesAsync()) list.Add(item);
        foreach (var item in await parent.GetFoldersAsync()) await RetriveFilesInFolders(list, item);
    }

    private async void Album_Tapped(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Load Tracks From Album
        TextBlock st = (TextBlock)sender;
        string albumname = st.Text;

        IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> ListOfSongs = (await folder.GetFilesAsync()).ToList();
        List<StorageFile> mylist = new List<StorageFile>();

        foreach(var file in ListOfSongs)
        {
            MusicProperties musicProperties = await file.Properties.GetMusicPropertiesAsync();
            if (musicProperties.Album == albumname)
                mylist.Add(file);
        }
    }
```

`mylist` contains now all my songs from the specific album. How do I play them with the audio player?

This is what I've got so far (but it doesn't work)

```
BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.SetFileSource(mylist[2]);
var message = new ValueSet();
message.Add(Constants.StartPlayback, "0");
BackgroundMediaPlayer.SendMessageToBackground(message);
```

I know it's a complicated way, but I didn't find a better solution for listing my albums in a ListView (or any View) and play all the songs from that album.

Comment: maybe it helps to you https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202978(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: You need Background task project and send it files to play. You can check out my work-in-progress music player on GitHub: https://github.com/nemecek-f/MusictasticReborn

Comment: @Filip I'll check it out later, thanks :)